# html code to always display a message which is inside a txt file

Tags: php, html, ajax

Question is Below. The aim is to display contents in txt file in an html.
Head of the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()  {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {  
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} else {  
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","news.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Display section body:

```
<div class="span-3" id="right-side">  <div id="myDiv">Your text here!
  </div><br><br><br><button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Click Here!</button>
```

But the problem, it requires user intervention. I don't want the button, the text is needed to be always displayed. What difference should i make?

Comment: How about this? `<div id="myDiv"><?php include('news.txt');?></div>`

Comment: It isn't working for me? I heard that i need to parse html. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your other question,
your code should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadXMLDoc()">
<div class="span-3" id="right-side">
    <div id="myDiv">
        Your text here!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()  {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else {  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","news.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

You can read more about onLoad event [Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event3.shtml)

Comment: This works as required for me. Any idea how i can marquee that text from bottom to top?

Comment: <marquee direction="up">text</marquee>

Comment: I want to marquee the data present at "news.txt". Want to add a thumbs up for your answer, but unable since i'm new.

Answer (score 0):

with marquee:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadXMLDoc()">
<div class="span-3" id="right-side">
    <div >
        <marquee direction="up" id="myDiv"></marquee>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()  {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else {  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","news.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

if you want to break the lines displayed, just add `<br>` tags inside your .txt file...

Comment: Thank You very much. I'll check this for working and come back. Sorry for being late.

Comment: Nope... marquee isn't displaying. I mean, no text is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

change your body tag to:

```
<body onLoad="loadXMLDoc()">
```

Comment: you mean to replace the second set of statements to one you said?

Comment: you replace only your body tag with the one i suggested. nothing else. you can remove the button if you want to.

Comment: Works well... any info how to marquee the text?